# How to prove point is vertex not interior point

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, polyhedra

Say we have a polyhedron represented by:

```
  x1 + x2 + 2*x3 <=3 
3*x1 + x2 +   x3 <=4
  x1,  x2,    x3 >= 0
```

how can I demonstrate that `(0,3,0)` is a vertex and not an interior point?

to make these equations instead of inequalities, we can use slack variables:

```
  x1 + x2 + 2*x3 + s1 = 3 
3*x1 + x2 +   x3 + s2 = 4
```

my guess is that at least one slack variable has to be 0. But it could also be only one slack variable can zero...not sure yet.

Comment: if someone could add the `polyhedron` tag that'd be great

Comment: yes, thanks, let me fix that

Comment: for example `(1,0,1)` satisfies both contraints, whereas `(0,3,0)` satisfies 1 constraint, I assume the first is a vertex, the 2nd isn't but couldn't tell you exactly why

Comment: From the point of view of calculus, this is a solid bounded by planes (setting the three inequalities to equalities) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. The edges are line segments in intersections of each two planes, the vertices the intersection of any two line segments, i.e., the intersection of any three planes. A polyhedron requires at least four faces (planes). Are you sure these are the only constraints?

Comment: yes you are right - the other constraints are all variables are >=0,  *all* variables, slack vars and regular vars. in other words all vars are non-negative.

Answer (score 2):

From the point of view of calculus, this is a solid bounded by planes (setting the three inequalities to equalities) in ℝ3. The edges are line segments in intersections of each two planes, $\textbf{the vertices the intersection of any two edges, i.e., the intersection of any three boundary planes.}$

All variables being nonnegative means that the other faces are given by $x=0,y=0,z=0$, or the $xy,yz,xz$-planes. And the polyhedron should be in the first octant (all variables nonnegative).

Note that $(0,3,0)$ lies in the three planes $x_1+x_2+2x_3=3, x=0, z=0$, so it must be a vertex.

Comment: yes, I think my answer is correct and is general, can you verify?

Comment: A vertex is the intersection of three boundary planes, meaning that three slack variables need to be 0.

Comment: yes, that jives with my answer, 3 variables can take on non-zero values, the other 3 have to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

In my estimation, to find a vertex, if you have N variables and M equations, at least (N-M) variables have to take on the value of 0.

this *smells* good:

1. N-M vars are `0`
2. equations are satisfied
3. all variables are non-negative

I believe (1) is **necessary**, and (2) is **necessary**, and given (3), then the total combination is **sufficient** for a point in a polyhedron to be a vertex.

(Without a restriction that all variables are +positive, it seems like there are pretty much always infinite solutions).